# What is best way to locate a collapsed panel in Protractor?

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I am very new to automation testing and looking for help to identify panel that is in collapsed state which I need to open to fill in details for form fields inside that panel.

I am trying with below xpath locator:

```
browser.findElement(by.className('panel-heading collapsed')).click();
```

Please let me know if I am doing it in a right way.

Webpage code:

```
<div class="panel-heading collapsed" id="menu-toggle2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo1" ng-click="tooglePanel('collapseTwo1')" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false"> 
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle panel-heading collapsed" id="menu-toggle2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo1" aria-expanded="false"> 
    <strong class="ng-binding">COMPANY DETAILS</strong> 
   </a> 
 </h4> 
</div>
```

Comment: Here is what webpage code looks like: <div class="panel-heading collapsed" id="menu-toggle2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo1" ng-click="tooglePanel('collapseTwo1')" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle panel-heading collapsed" id="menu-toggle2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo1" aria-expanded="false">
               <strong class="ng-binding">COMPANY DETAILS</strong>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the selector you are using is that there are multiple elements using the classes `panel-heading collapsed`. You need something more unique. In this case I would probably use the `ng-click()` attribute on this element. Something like the following should work:

```
browser.findElement(by.css('div[ng-click="tooglePanel('collapseTwo1')"]').click();
```

Another option is to use link text:

```
browser.findElement(by.linkText('COMPANY DETAILS').click();
```